# ElasticSearch: List of all documents by index [No handler found for uri]

Tags: curl, elasticsearch

I'm trying to get the list of all documents by the index:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/myindex'
```

But get:

> No handler found for uri [/myindex] and method [GET]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to view all of the documents in the index, you will need to execute a search using post:

```
 curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/myindex/_search'
      -d '{"query":{"match_all":{}}, "size":100}'
```

This requests the first 100 documents from your index. You can get more details on querying an index from the [Search API](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-search.html) and [Query DSL](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-queries.html) documentation.

Comment: its the separate question, but its too small and I'm sure that you know the answer. `Question`: can the next query totally clear all indexes: `curl -XDELETE localhost:9200 -d '{"match" : {"message" : "this is a test"}}'`?

Comment: Follow the guidelines in Delete By Query API - http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html